# Run Node.js Shell_Exec command onclick

Tags: node.js, shell, express, pug

I'm building a home automation system in NodeJS and I want to fire some commands on my raspberry pi using the Shell_exec function in Express. How can I do this with an onclick event in JADE?

This is my app.js in Express:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var shell_exec = require('shell_exec').shell_exec;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/homeapp');

var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images', 'favicon-32x32.png')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
var User = require('./models/User');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

module.exports = app;
```

And this is my index.js with the routing:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var auth = require('../controller/AuthController.js');

router.get('/', auth.home);

router.get('/login', auth.login);

router.post('/login', auth.doLogin);

router.get('/logout', auth.logout);

module.exports = router;
```

And this is the jade file where I want the onclick event to exucute the commands:

```
div.btn(onclick="shell_exec");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call any Node.js command from Jade view. Jade view is parsed in client's browser and any javascript commands you write in that file will be executed in browser.

In the view you should add code which will create AJAX request to the node.js server and in the node.js app create route which will handle the request and execute the command (shell_exec).